# How to sort array of objects by properties with only one function?

Tags: arrays, typescript, sorting

I have this Array:

```js
const list = [
    { color: 'white', size: 'XXL' },
    { color: 'red', size: 'XL' },
    { color: 'black', size: 'M' }
]
```

I want to sort it by the values of `color` or `size`:

```js
colorSort = () => {
    list.sort((a, b) => (a.color > b.color) ? 1 : -1)
}
    
sizeSort = () => {
    list.sort((a, b) => (a.size> b.size) ? 1 : -1)
}
```

I don't like to create 2 functions for sorting.

Is there any way to create a function like this:

```js
sortArray = (value:string = 'color') => {
     #code here
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try this:

```js
function by<T extends keyof U, U>(property: T): (a: U, b: U) => number {
    return (a, b) => {
        return a[property] < b[property] ? -1 : a[property] > b[property] ? 1 : 0;
    };
}

const list = [
    { color: 'white', size: 'XXL' },
    { color: 'red', size: 'XL' },
    { color: 'black', size: 'M' }
];

const listSortedByColor = [...list].sort(by("color"));

const listSortedBySize = [...list].sort(by("size"));
```

Here we use the function `by` to create compare functions which can be passed as an argument to the Array.sort method. We can use TypeScript's advanced typing system to make sure that `by` is type-safe allowing only properties as arguments that actually exist in the objects you want to sort.

**And Remember:** [Array.sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) is in-place. :-)